# Typescript (() => void) | undefined ':' expected.ts(1005)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

guys! I have some small problem with typing react props.

I have function deletePost, that I want forward to component AuthorPostsList, but I always got a warning but typescript: (property) AuthorPostsListProps.delete?: (() => void) | undefined ':' expected.ts(1005).

deletePost:

```
const deletePost = () =>{
   console.log('test! post was deleted')
}
```

AuthorPostsList:

```
interface AuthorPostsListProps{
    posts: IPost[];
    me: boolean;
    delete?: () => void;
}

const AuthorPostsList: FC<AuthorPostsListProps> = ({posts, me, delete}) => {

    return (
        <div className='author-list'>
            {posts.map(post => 
                <AuthorPostsItem me={me} key={post._id} post={post}/>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
export default AuthorPostsList;
```

forwarding into AuthorPostsList:

```
<AuthorPostsList me={true} delete={deletePost} posts={posts} />
```

I'm confused. I don't understand what am i doing wrong. Help with advice. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `delete` is a javascript keyword and cannot be used an identifier, though it can be an object property name.

```
const obj = { delete: () => null } // fine
const { delete } = obj // error
```

So you cannot have local variable named `delete`, as you do from destructuring your props.

---

Changing that to `deletePost` may fix your problem.

Comment: it can be renamed in destructuring too, `const { delete: deletePost } = obj`